# How to find the spectrum of the localization of $k[x]$ at $(x)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, I wonder how to find the spectrum of $k[x]$ at $(x)$.

I know the prime ideals of $k[x]$ are ideals generated by irreducible polynomials, but I have no ideas what prime ideals should look like in $k[x]_{(x)}$.

Any solution or reference will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: For any commutative ring $R$ and prime ideal $P$, the prime ideals of $R$ localized at $P$ are in bijection with the primes of $R$ that are contained in $P$. So your question can be answered by instead looking at the prime ideals of $k[x]$ contained in $(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution:

> As Brandon Carter pointed out, any prime ideal $Q$ of $R:=k[x]_{(x)}$ corresponds to a prime ideal of $k[x]$ which is contained in $(x)$. But $(x)$ has height (at most) one by [Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem). Hence, it does not properly contain any prime ideal other than $(0)$. Consequently, those are the only two prime ideals of $R$.